# How can I get Azure API Management to document the body for the request when using swagger?

Tags: swagger, azure-api-management

We are using swagger 2.0 to document our .Net Web API's which we are hosting in Azure behind Azure API Management. I am having troubles getting the documentation to detail the complex objects that are being posted as part of the body. Azure shows no details about the object at all leaving me to have to document them myself. Below is the json file that I imported into Azure API Management.

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "Hotel Search",
        "description": "The seodecnvewjkl"
    },
    "basePath": "/v1",
    "consumes": [
        "application/xml",
        "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
        "application/xml",
        "application/json"
    ],
    "schemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/hotels/search": {
            "post": {
                "operationId": "searchCommand",
                "description": "Searches for hotels",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "hotelSearchRq",
                        "in": "body",
                        "required": true,
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/HotelSearchRq"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful response",
                        "schema": {
                            "title": "HotelSearchRs",
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/HotelSearchRs"
                        }
                    },
                    "400": {
                        "description": "Bad Request"
                    },
                    "404": {
                        "description": "Unauthorised"
                    }
                }
            },
            "get": {
                "operationId": "searchQuery",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "CorrelationId",
                        "in": "query",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "Successful response"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "StayDetail": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "NumberOfGuests": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "CheckinDate": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "format": "date",
                    "description": "the date that the stay starts from"
                }
            }
        },
        "HotelSearchCriteria": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "MaximumResults": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                },
                "StayDetails": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/StayDetail"
                }
            }
        },
        "HotelSearchRq": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "CustomerTransactionIdentifier": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "The customers transaction identifier"
                },
                "search_criteria": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/HotelSearchCriteria"
                }
            }
        },
        "HotelSearchRs": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```

[Azure Api Management operation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOW3m.png)

Can someone please help me with how I can get the body documented automatically from the swagger documentation?

Comment: I know this feature has been worked on recently.  Let me try and get you more information on when it will be available.

Comment: Thanks for this Darrel, do you have any idea when it might be available? It is just that it would help us a lot because we are potentially going to have 40+ API's that we would need to document all the request and response bodies separately.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any timeline for that.  The feature that I had heard about was the ability to validate responses based on schema.  If importing schema and example responses for display on the docs is important to you then might I suggest adding a suggestion to the feedback site https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management  Thanks.

Comment: One additional comment though and feel free to take it or leave it.  My experience with building APIs has led me to the conclusion that documenting structures that specific to a particular URL/request/response leads to a significant amount of duplication.  Defining a vocabulary for your problem domain, the valid structures and relationships between their structures is a more precise way of describing your domain that can then be reused across many resources/APIs.  e.g. https://github.com/darrelmiller/conference-talk/blob/master/conference-talk.md

Comment: Disappointing to see that in 2017 that this is still not resolved

Comment: @DarrelMiller Not entirely sure where you are going with your last comment but the fact remains that members within our corporation as well as external contractors and affiliates cannot use our API because the API gateway, in this case APIM, neglects to mention what parameters and/or body is required.   Talk of duplication is irrelevant when talking about an API gateway.  If people are worried about duplication they wouldn't use an API gateway in the first place and simply use the underlying REST API and refer to the Swagger doco.

Comment: @DarrelMiller ...It's clear that there is an intention for APIM to document imported APIs but just seems to be not fully there yet.  If the intent was not to "duplicate" then we wouldn't see any API documentation at all in APIM Publisher and DEV portals which clearly isn't the case

Comment: @MickyD  The perspective I have personally and that of APIM are different.  I completely understand the desire to describe in detail an API surface area.  And to my knowledge this is now fully implemented in Azure API Management.  If something is not working for you, let us know and we will investigate.

Comment: @DarrelMiller Thanks, can you investigate please as per my comment below - we're using nested `$refs` as per the OP's example

Answer (score 1):

Currently the request and response body information from a Swagger doc are not displayed in the developer portal documentation.

This is no longer the case.  Samples and schema are displayed in the developer portal.

Comment: @MickyD  It works for all but two scenarios that I am aware of.  If you don't have a produces/consumes it won't show, or if you have nested $refs in your schemas.

Comment: I have produces+consumes as well as nested `$refs` - exactly as per the OP's example

Comment: @MickyD  Sorry, didn't notice the nested $refs in the above example.  Fixing that is high on my to-do list.

Comment: @DarrelMiller i'm both using produces/consumes and **not** using $refs in my swagger, but the request parameters still don't show up in the API-operation-request definition. The "multipart/form-data" tab is empty.

Comment: @JurajPaulo  Can you post an example of the problem document in a new question and tag me and I will investigate the issue?